# I selected D1(shared) for 9$ option while setting custom domain in Azure. Now will I pay those 9$?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services, azure-app-service-plans

I created a free account in Azure.com.For custom domain I chose D1(shared) option for 9$. Now the issue is, my total free credit are still 200$ how? Will I pay 9$ from my credit card? Since it's totally free account and they will not charge unless I convert my account to Pay-As-You-Go subscription. Even they delete it after the trail. I tried to talk with their support they told me that it's free and you will not be charged, but my 200$ credits are still there.
You can see in the image what option I chose:
[image: Screeshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $9.67 is the cost of running this app for 1 month. So if you create this app on the first of the month and let it run through the 30th, then you would be left with $190.33 azure credits.

When you create the app the 9.67 is not charged upfront but rather you would be charged about $0.013 per hour.

So if the app is there for 24 hours for 30 days then that would be $0.013 * 24(hours in a day) * 30(days in a month)  =  $9.67 aprox.

Comment: Oh yes. You are right. And in after a month, my $190.33 credits will be discarded right? On the end of the free trial. And it's right that they will close my account automatically? If I don't subscribe any paid subscription.